# Reading a file in R columns are separated with multiple space

Tags: r, readfile

I'm trying to load a file, file columns separated with space, but there are different number of space 
between columns. because of this while i'm reading, R thing every space is another column and producing extra empty columns. Is there any other way to load data without problem.

Example Data :

```
AAT_ECOLI   0.49  0.29  0.48  0.50  0.56  0.24  0.35   cp
ACEA_ECOLI  0.07  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.54  0.35  0.44   cp
ACEK_ECOLI  0.56  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.49  0.37  0.46   cp
ACKA_ECOLI  0.59  0.49  0.48  0.50  0.52  0.45  0.36   cp
```

you can see that, between first column and second there 3 space, and 2nd column and 3th column there are two space.

I'm using this code for loading data

```
xxx <- read.csv("../Datasets/Ecoli/ecoli.data", header=FALSE,sep=" ")
```

I tried 3 space or other things but none of them worked.

Original data file :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_XEmkrWR-hCMXVySVI2bU5waGs/view?usp=sharing
Thank you

Comment: If it's space-separated, then it's not a csv. `read.table` might be more appropriate.  Try `sep = "\t"`

Comment: When i use it, it is only storing all with in one column, i want that, 9 columns

Comment: I tried, read.table also but result is same

Comment: Or simpler: `read.delim` if it's space-separated, @RichardScriven.

Comment: @docendodiscimus - Perhaps in general, but scroll down to my answer :) `read.table` is fine for this data

Comment: I was referring to your comment.. @RichardScriven. The answer is nice, indeed.

Comment: I've actually never used `read.delim`, but I see your point now after skimming the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.table` works perfectly on your downloaded data set.  No arguments other than `file` are necessary (unless you don't want factors).  I tend to reserve `read.csv` for files that are actually comma-separated.

```
df <- read.table("Downloads/ecoli.data")
str(df)
# 'data.frame':    336 obs. of  9 variables:
#  $ V1: Factor w/ 336 levels "AAS_ECOLI","AAT_ECOLI",..: 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 12 ...
#  $ V2: num  0.49 0.07 0.56 0.59 0.23 0.67 0.29 0.21 0.2 0.42 ...
#  $ V3: num  0.29 0.4 0.4 0.49 0.32 0.39 0.28 0.34 0.44 0.4 ...
#  $ V4: num  0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 ...
#  $ V5: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
#  $ V6: num  0.56 0.54 0.49 0.52 0.55 0.36 0.44 0.51 0.46 0.56 ...
#  $ V7: num  0.24 0.35 0.37 0.45 0.25 0.38 0.23 0.28 0.51 0.18 ...
#  $ V8: num  0.35 0.44 0.46 0.36 0.35 0.46 0.34 0.39 0.57 0.3 ...
#  $ V9: Factor w/ 8 levels "cp","im","imL",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: I actually can't believe the other answer has been marked as accepted.... SO is so strange....

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `strip.white=T` and `sep=''` :

```
xxx <- read.csv("c:\\r_stack_overflow\\test.csv", header=FALSE, strip.white=T, sep='')

> xxx
          V1   V2   V3   V4  V5   V6   V7   V8 V9
1  AAT_ECOLI 0.49 0.29 0.48 0.5 0.56 0.24 0.35 cp
2 ACEA_ECOLI 0.07 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.54 0.35 0.44 cp
3 ACEK_ECOLI 0.56 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.49 0.37 0.46 cp
4 ACKA_ECOLI 0.59 0.49 0.48 0.5 0.52 0.45 0.36 cp

> dim(xxx)
[1] 4 9
```

And it works!

**UPDATE:**

It works perfect with your data too:

```
xxx <- read.csv("c:\\r_stack_overflow\\ecoli.data", header=FALSE, strip.white=T, sep='')
```

Output:

```
> xxx
            V1   V2   V3   V4  V5   V6   V7   V8  V9
1    AAT_ECOLI 0.49 0.29 0.48 0.5 0.56 0.24 0.35  cp
2   ACEA_ECOLI 0.07 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.54 0.35 0.44  cp
3   ACEK_ECOLI 0.56 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.49 0.37 0.46  cp
4   ACKA_ECOLI 0.59 0.49 0.48 0.5 0.52 0.45 0.36  cp
5    ADI_ECOLI 0.23 0.32 0.48 0.5 0.55 0.25 0.35  cp
6   ALKH_ECOLI 0.67 0.39 0.48 0.5 0.36 0.38 0.46  cp
7   AMPD_ECOLI 0.29 0.28 0.48 0.5 0.44 0.23 0.34  cp
8   AMY2_ECOLI 0.21 0.34 0.48 0.5 0.51 0.28 0.39  cp
9    APT_ECOLI 0.20 0.44 0.48 0.5 0.46 0.51 0.57  cp
10  ARAC_ECOLI 0.42 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.56 0.18 0.30  cp
11  ASG1_ECOLI 0.42 0.24 0.48 0.5 0.57 0.27 0.37  cp
12  BTUR_ECOLI 0.25 0.48 0.48 0.5 0.44 0.17 0.29  cp
13  CAFA_ECOLI 0.39 0.32 0.48 0.5 0.46 0.24 0.35  cp
14  CAIB_ECOLI 0.51 0.50 0.48 0.5 0.46 0.32 0.35  cp
15   CFA_ECOLI 0.22 0.43 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.16 0.28  cp
16  CHEA_ECOLI 0.25 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.46 0.44 0.52  cp
17  CHEB_ECOLI 0.34 0.45 0.48 0.5 0.38 0.24 0.35  cp
18  CHEW_ECOLI 0.44 0.27 0.48 0.5 0.55 0.52 0.58  cp
19  CHEY_ECOLI 0.23 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.39 0.28 0.38  cp
20  CHEZ_ECOLI 0.41 0.57 0.48 0.5 0.39 0.21 0.32  cp
21   CRL_ECOLI 0.40 0.45 0.48 0.5 0.38 0.22 0.00  cp
22  CSPA_ECOLI 0.31 0.23 0.48 0.5 0.73 0.05 0.14  cp
23  CYNR_ECOLI 0.51 0.54 0.48 0.5 0.41 0.34 0.43  cp
24  CYPB_ECOLI 0.30 0.16 0.48 0.5 0.56 0.11 0.23  cp
25  CYPC_ECOLI 0.36 0.39 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.22 0.23  cp
26  CYSB_ECOLI 0.29 0.37 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.44 0.52  cp
27  CYSE_ECOLI 0.25 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.47 0.33 0.42  cp
28  DAPD_ECOLI 0.21 0.51 0.48 0.5 0.50 0.32 0.41  cp
29   DCP_ECOLI 0.43 0.37 0.48 0.5 0.53 0.35 0.44  cp
30  DDLA_ECOLI 0.43 0.39 0.48 0.5 0.47 0.31 0.41  cp
31  DDLB_ECOLI 0.53 0.38 0.48 0.5 0.44 0.26 0.36  cp
32  DEOC_ECOLI 0.34 0.33 0.48 0.5 0.38 0.35 0.44  cp
33  DLDH_ECOLI 0.56 0.51 0.48 0.5 0.34 0.37 0.46  cp
34   EFG_ECOLI 0.40 0.29 0.48 0.5 0.42 0.35 0.44  cp
35  EFTS_ECOLI 0.24 0.35 0.48 0.5 0.31 0.19 0.31  cp
36  EFTU_ECOLI 0.36 0.54 0.48 0.5 0.41 0.38 0.46  cp
37   ENO_ECOLI 0.29 0.52 0.48 0.5 0.42 0.29 0.39  cp
38  FABB_ECOLI 0.65 0.47 0.48 0.5 0.59 0.30 0.40  cp
39   FES_ECOLI 0.32 0.42 0.48 0.5 0.35 0.28 0.38  cp
40  G3P1_ECOLI 0.38 0.46 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.22 0.29  cp
41  G3P2_ECOLI 0.33 0.45 0.48 0.5 0.52 0.32 0.41  cp
42  G6PI_ECOLI 0.30 0.37 0.48 0.5 0.59 0.41 0.49  cp
43  GCVA_ECOLI 0.40 0.50 0.48 0.5 0.45 0.39 0.47  cp
44  GLNA_ECOLI 0.28 0.38 0.48 0.5 0.50 0.33 0.42  cp
45  GLPD_ECOLI 0.61 0.45 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.35 0.41  cp
46  GLYA_ECOLI 0.17 0.38 0.48 0.5 0.45 0.42 0.50  cp
47  GSHR_ECOLI 0.44 0.35 0.48 0.5 0.55 0.55 0.61  cp
48    GT_ECOLI 0.43 0.40 0.48 0.5 0.39 0.28 0.39  cp
49  HEM6_ECOLI 0.42 0.35 0.48 0.5 0.58 0.15 0.27  cp
50  HEMN_ECOLI 0.23 0.33 0.48 0.5 0.43 0.33 0.43  cp
51  HPRT_ECOLI 0.37 0.52 0.48 0.5 0.42 0.42 0.36  cp
52   IF1_ECOLI 0.29 0.30 0.48 0.5 0.45 0.03 0.17  cp
53   IF2_ECOLI 0.22 0.36 0.48 0.5 0.35 0.39 0.47  cp
54  ILVY_ECOLI 0.23 0.58 0.48 0.5 0.37 0.53 0.59  cp
55  IPYR_ECOLI 0.47 0.47 0.48 0.5 0.22 0.16 0.26  cp
56   KAD_ECOLI 0.54 0.47 0.48 0.5 0.28 0.33 0.42  cp
57  KDSA_ECOLI 0.51 0.37 0.48 0.5 0.35 0.36 0.45  cp
58  LEU3_ECOLI 0.40 0.35 0.48 0.5 0.45 0.33 0.42  cp
59   LON_ECOLI 0.44 0.34 0.48 0.5 0.30 0.33 0.43  cp
60  LPLA_ECOLI 0.42 0.38 0.48 0.5 0.54 0.34 0.43  cp
61  LYSR_ECOLI 0.44 0.56 0.48 0.5 0.50 0.46 0.54  cp
62  MALQ_ECOLI 0.52 0.36 0.48 0.5 0.41 0.28 0.38  cp
63  MALZ_ECOLI 0.36 0.41 0.48 0.5 0.48 0.47 0.54  cp
64  MASY_ECOLI 0.18 0.30 0.48 0.5 0.46 0.24 0.35  cp
65  METB_ECOLI 0.47 0.29 0.48 0.5 0.51 0.33 0.43  cp
66  METC_ECOLI 0.24 0.43 0.48 0.5 0.54 0.52 0.59  cp
67  METK_ECOLI 0.25 0.37 0.48 0.5 0.41 0.33 0.42  cp
```

And dimensions:

```
> dim(xxx)
[1] 336   9
```

Comment: Hi LyzandeR, thank for your replay but i'm getting this error when i add stip.white=T.

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (stip.white = TRUE)

Comment: `strip.white` not `stip.white`

Comment: @eipi10 thank you for correction, i corrected it, but now i'm getting another error, 

    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip,     nlines, na.strings,  : 
      line 2 did not have 19 elements

Comment: I uploaded data file, you can data

Comment: I found the mistake, i saw it now that, i missed to sep='' this. 
Thanks a lot it worked

Comment: @docendodiscimus Because I just wanted to use the same function as the OP. I haven't marked the answer as accepted, the OP did. Feel free to contact the OP and tell him/her to change the accepted answer to Richard's. I only use read.csv for csv delimited files myself. The OP used this initially and I just wanted to figure out whether I can use this to solve the problem. The answer was marked as accepted before Richard answered the question. I can't change the accepted answer myself. Otherwise, I would. I thought SO was a friendly place...

Comment: Okay, I understand your point. I really didn't mean to offend you with my comment so I'll delete it.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for changing the accepted answer seleucia. Too much peer pressure for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but I believe this should work:

```
file_df <- scan('data.txt', what = list("","","","","","","","",""))
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(file_df), nrow=4))
```